# Can MySQL return the columns from a "max" row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data in a table :-

```
Student     Subject     Marks
Peter       English     85
Peter       Maths       79
Peter       Science     80
Milind      English     71
Milind      Maths       95
Milind      Science     89
```

I want to write a query which will give me for each student, the subject in which s/he scored max. In this case, it will be

```
Peter   English
Milind  Maths
```

Thanks in advance for the help.
Milind.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: what if a student has same marks in 2 subjects and these are max which subject will be considered with max() mark.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Answer (score 2):

You could do like below:

```
SELECT 
  t1.Student, t1.Subject
FROM your_table t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(Marks) AS max_marks, Subject 
  FROM your_table
  GROUP BY Subject
) t2 ON t1.Subject = t2.Subject AND t1.Marks = t2.max_marks
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do , but in case a student has 2 max marks it will list only one of them

```
select
t1.Student,
t1.Subject,
t2.Marks from
table_name t1
join
(
  select 
  Student,
  max(Marks) as Marks
  from table_name 
  group by Student
)t2
on t2.Student = t1.Student AND t2.Marks = t1.Marks 
group by t1.Student;
```

If you need both max() marks subjects to be displayed in case there are, then the last group by needs to be changed to

```
group by t1.Student,t1.Subject;
```

Here is a **[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df2cf/2)** to illustrate both of them.

Answer (score 0):

there are few ways to do, you can try this solution

```
select
    t1.*
from 
    your_table t1 
    left join your_table t2 on t1.Student = t2.Student and t1.Marks < t2.Marks
where
    t2.Marks is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this should work : **Please revert in case of any Clarifications.**

**"StudentMarks is the name of the table"**

;With MaxMarks as 
(
Select Name, Subject_, Marks as Highmarks from StudentMarks
Group by Name, Subject_, Marks
)

Select * from MaxMarks where Highmarks in 
(Select Max(Highmarks) from MaxMarks 
Group by Name
)

Answer (score -1):

You can combine multiple queries, so something like this:

> SELECT * FROM students WHERE Student='Peter' AND Marks=( SELECT MAX(Marks) WHERE Student='Peter' )

Note that this is untested.

Comment: The query should be universal, not hard-coded. Also its strange and does not return the required output.